# Touch Designer - MIDI input edrums doesn't work correctly

Tags: syntax-error, sencha-touch, padding, midi

I'm trying to connect my electric drum > gear4music edrums DD70, the software recognizes the drum and the channels to the associated pads but it doesn't give me a numerical value. see attached photos.
Do you know what could be the problem?

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGTsS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ymsc.png)

Each selected channel should return a numeric value and then through the speed node I should be able to slow down the calculation of this value over time.